# Не добавляются покупки в joomshopping

Tags: joomla, корзина

http://kaminare.ru/ 
Есть сайт, хром выдает ошибку только на интерпретатор less, однако проблема в другом.

Корзина работает только в хроме и лисе на компьютере, с мобильного телефона ни в сафари ни в других браузерах не работает, ie 8 не работает, другие не тестировал, но боюсь что проблема та же.

Пробовал ставить шаблон в JShopping на default, менял стандартный джумловский на протостар, отключал ЧПУ, выключал все модули, никакого эффекта.

Это полюбому какой то скрипт же, да? Или конфликт скриптов. Где бы мне что то вроде логов посмотреть?